# Adjust Bootstrap image resizing

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a card div with two images inside, an up arrow and a down arrow.

When in full screen the images look okay and are the full size but due to Bootstraps responsive design, when i reduce the page resolution using the developer console in chrome, the images get smaller and smaller until they cannot be seen on a small device, such as a mobile.

How can i limit how small the images will go?

Thanks.

```
<div class='col-11 col-xs-11 col-md-5 col-lg-5' style='background-color:#dfdfdf;border-radius:5px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;'>

  <div class='col-2 col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2'>
      <h4 class='card-header' style='text-align:center;height:100%;'> 
        <img style='height:50%;'src='uparrow' onmouseover=this.src='differentuparrow' onmouseout=this.src='uparrow' border='0'/>
        <br><br>
        <img style='height:50%; src='downarrow' onmouseover=this.src='differentdownarrow' onmouseout=this.src='downarrow' border='0'/>
      </h4>
   </div>

  <div class='col-8 col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8'>
     <h4 class='card-header' style=''><u>Title</u></h4>
     <div class='card-body' style=''>
       <p class='card-title'>Description</p>
       <p class='card-text' style='display: inline-block; bottom:0;'>Points: 0<br>Replies: 0</p>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-2 col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2' style='float:right;'>
     <i class='fa fa-pencil fa-5' aria-hidden='true'> Edit</i>
     <br> <i class='fa fa-trash fa-5' aria-hidden='true'> Delete</i>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5a87h3ky/

I had to remove the original sources for the images due to confidentiality

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please edit your question and post a complete code snippet that we can use to test and troubleshoot things. There are too many variables otherwise.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5a87h3ky/

i made a jsfiddle for it but for some reason it looks completely different to my live implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the minimum size of the image using the `min-width: px;` attribute.

This will prevent the image from getting any smaller than the given size.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of controlling the size of images with CSS or in HTML. To control your arrows you can use min-height and max-height and also set min-width and max-width.

For example take image_arrow_up.jpg, you can set it's size with:

```
<head>
<style>
div {
    max-height: 600px;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Another way would be to use percentages, although this is not as concrete as min and max:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

img.one {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

img.two {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

Another option is to use CSS with the `image-set` function, or with `scrset` + `sizes`:

```
.img {
  background-image: url(examples/images/image-384.jpg);
  background-image: 
    -webkit-image-set(
      url(examples/images/image-384.jpg) 1x,
      url(examples/images/image-768.jpg) 2x,
    );
  background-image: 
    image-set(
      url(examples/images/image-384.jpg) 1x,
      url(examples/images/image-768.jpg) 2x,
    );
}
```

It also helps to make sure the original image is sized appropriately. For example make the original arrow image sized for a "regular" desktop monitor rather than an oversized arrow that may shrink in unexpected ways.  Or you can use an image management service, such as Cloudinary or 3Scale to create [responsive quality](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/responsive_images) images.